# git cvsimport complains about invalid SHA1

Tags: git, cvs

I am using `git-cvsimport` on Debian 6.0 to import a CVS repository to a bare git repository.  I create a directoy `project.git`.

```
cd project.git

cvsps -x -u -g -r MCKINLEY -v --norc cvsmodulename >& ../output.txt

/usr/lib/git-core/git-cvsimport  -v -i -p r,MKCKINLEY -P ../output.txt modulename
```

It works for a long time and then I get the error saying:

```
* UNKNOWN LINE * symbol given -r : MCKINLEY: not found
DONE; creating master branch
fatal: refs/heads/origin: not a valid SHA1
fatal: master not a valid SHA1
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You have both `MCKINLEY` and `MKCKINLEY` and I fixed a typo in your output ("maser"). Can you paste the exact commands and output?

Comment: So I changed my strategy and did it the following way and I am running into another error: mkdir test; cd test; cvs co -r rev module; cvsps --norc -a -v -x -u  &> cvsps.out;  /usr/lib/git-core/git-cvsimport -v and after some cvs rlog activities I get cvs rlog: Logging products/local/etc
git cvsimport: fatal: cvsps reported error

Comment: this approach was leading me nowhere. Switched to cvs2git and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cvs2git was the approach I took that worked...